# write me an arduino code that will send a message using gsm module(Sim800L) when a buzer is sounding (active)

Tags: arduino-uno

I tapped a high signal from a buzzer, i need an arduino uno code that will send a message using gsm module(Sim800L) when the buzer is alarming (active).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: start by writing a program that turns on an LED ... when that works then write a program that turns on an LED when buzzer sounds